# modifying objects passed from component to service

Tags: angular

I'm trying to refactor my code by putting common component methods into a shared service, however I'm not sure why I can't seem to overwrite a component's public object property passed to the service, although I do appear to be able to modify specific object properties.

To be specific this doesn't work:

Component:

```
   public data: any;    

    ngOnInit(): void {
       loadData(this.data);
       console.log(this.data); // <-- returns undefined
    }
```

Service Method:

```
loadData(data) {
    data = {test:'test'};
}
```

HOWEVER, if i were pass an object like { test: 'test' } to the service and just modify it in the service (e.g. set data.test = 'test2'), that appears to work...the component will have the modified value, as I would expect.

My question is, why doesn't can't I assign a new *object* to the object passed to the service, given that objects are supposedly passed by reference? Is angular doing something to protect the component property from mutating, and if so, can it be by passed?

btw, I understand I could simply return a value from loadData and do the assignment in the component, however, this doesn't help with more complicated methods that I want to refactor, that may have multiple objects being passed to the service and modified in the service method.

Any insights appreciated.

-S. Arora

Answer (score 1):

You still can update your component data. But it would look like this:

```
loadData(data) {
    data.test = 'test';
}
```

Since you only want to override just object's property, this would be enough. Although I would add condition to check if object exists since without checking this would throw error. So perhaps:

```
loadData(data) {
  if (data) {
    data.test = 'test';
  }
}
```

Why your case didn't work, I'm not 100% confident, but it might be because you're trying to assign a completely new object (new reference) while in my case the reference stays the same.

Comment: I appreciate the response. Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I'm aware that I'm able to update properties, but the issue is with assigning the object passed by reference with a new value entirely. I wish I understood what it was (e.g. javascript thing or else angular specific) that i'm bumping into, and what my options are, so that I can determine how to refactor a lot of redundant code.

Comment: Your comment got me thinking that by doing an assignment it breaks the object reference. For now I guess in my loadData method i can do something like data = Object.assign(data, {test:'test'}) instead to keep the object reference. If anyone has any other related suggestions on how to maintain the object reference I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I see. Well, another option is to do an assignment to `this.data` in component, but you would do that once, and in service you would return an entire object. Why you cannot assign the way you wrote, I'm actually not so sure. Usually ("usually" as speaking only for myself) you don't pass an object to overwrite with another object, instead you return a new object and do the assignment on component or you update only some fields.

Comment: To add more, another reason why I don't think it's a good idea to modify on service-level is because much later in development you might face a situation where you get unexpected values. And if you split assignments/updates between multiple files, it might be hard to track the changes. :)

Comment: Overall problem is i have 4 components doing similar things, and a lot of the component methods are the same e.g. load the data, or modify a specific property based on conditions such as the value of another property. Because these methods may rely on several components properties, and I want to modify more than one property, i need an approach that works more robustly than just taking a single input and returning it. i.e. a way to move the component methods to the service that works in general, not just for the one example.

Comment: Another approach, if you have some conditions, is it do something like `this.data = load(this.data);` and in service you add conditions (assuming conditions are the same for all components) and in the end you still return a newly created/modified object. Since I cannot see a whole picture, I'm doing some assumptions what you currently have.

Comment: Yup, that works to a point, unless I have to modify multiple objects in the same method. I appreciate the feedback...good to have refactoring options!

Comment: I hope I helped you enough :) Good luck!